# How to put change in store redux-form

Tags: field, redux-form, react-admin

I'm using react-autosuggest for make a autocomplete input (fetch on type). My code is based on `AutoCompleteArrayInput` from react-admin and react-autosuggest in material-ui. And I decorate my component with `addField` for using redux-form with.

But has the fetch and the selection is working good, when I put my component in a `SimpleForm` all the input have a value in the redux store but not mine. When I look in react dev tools, there is a `Field` component arround my component

I try to do it manually via `change` from redux-form but it doesn't work.
How can I connect my component in the redux store for submit all my input ?

```
export default connect(
  null,
  {
    getSearched: crudGetAll,
  },
)(
  compose(
    addField,
    translate,
  )(ButtonSearchWithAutocompletion),
);
```

```
onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion }) => {
    const { onSelectedValue, source } = this.props;

    change(REDUX_FORM_NAME, source, suggestion.id);
    onSelectedValue(suggestion);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in my team help me to solve the problem, for anybody facing the same issue, the solution was, to put the `change` of `redux-form` in my index.js like this :

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';

import ButtonSearchWithAutocompletion from './component';

export default connect(
  null,
  {
    getSearched: crudGetAll,
    change,
  },
)(
  compose(
    addField,
    translate,
  )(ButtonSearchWithAutocompletion),
);
```

And in my component.js I use the `change` as props :

```
onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion }) => {
    const { onSelectedValue, source, change } = this.props;

    change(REDUX_FORM_NAME, source, suggestion.id);
    onSelectedValue(suggestion);
  };
```

Hope this help !